# Can a sentence have multiple predicates?

Tags: subjects, predicate

I was doing an exercise from my grammar book where one has to identify the subject and the predicate when I stumbled across the following sentence.

> A barking sound the shepherd hears.

Now I know that 'the shepherd' is the subject but I am not able to identify predicate. My book says that the predicate is 'A barking sound... hears'.
But I am not entirely convinced of the above answer because I think that the predicate is supposed to a phrase.

My guess is that both 'A barking sound' and 'hears' are the predicates of the given sentence.

Does anyone know whether or not a sentence can have multiple predicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence has inverted word order where the noun phrase serving as the direct object comes first, then the subject, and finally the verb.

In normal order, your sentence reads:

> The shepherd hears a barking sound.

*hears a barking sound* is still the full predicate; it is merely split by the inversion.

A sentence may easily have a compound predicate:

> I bought a bag of carrots but left it at the store.

*bought a bag of carrots* and *left it at the store* form a compound predicate joined by a coordinating conjunction.

But that's not really what you're asking.